# Lucene to Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I would like to translate Lucene code to Elasticsearch code in a product, what is the easiest way to do?
And can the Lucene's query be used in  Elasticsearch ? after all, a lot of code are about query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lucene query syntax within the Query String Query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)